# How to run/start VsCode in Centos 7

Tags: visual-studio-code, centos, centos7

I have installed **vscode** on a remote server(*which means I have to use ssh*) running on **Centos 7**. The version of **vscode** is `1.54.3`.

When I run `code`, the line get executed but the **vscode** does not start. When I try `/usr/share/code/code` I get an error

> :FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(158)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /usr/share/code/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.

I have tried solving it using

```
cd /usr/share/code/
sudo chown root:root chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox
```

and

```
/usr/share/code/code --no-sandbox
```

But it does not work.
Where could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me

- Reboot the host after installation
- Update vscode: `sudo yum update code`
- Change directory: `cd /usr/share/code`
- Run: `sudo chown root:root chrome-sandbox`
- Run: `sudo chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox`
- Start vscode: `code .`

Answer (score 0):

The latest version that is supported in CENTOS 7 is 1.53. You can download it from the developer's website: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53

Comment: The last version supporting CentOS 7 is 1.52.